# How to import nodejs module "module" via es6 import to create "require" function with "createRequire" in order to use node's "require"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am writing a JavaScript es6 module which contains "Mocha" test-cases which test a JavaScript es6 module containing the actual functionality of my app.

I am trying to import nodejs module "module" via es6 import like so:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
```

Next I create a "require" function by calling "createRequire":

```
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Afterwards I try to use "require" to import nodejs modules:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;
```

I put that all together in a HTML file, started a web-server and opened the HTML file in the browser.

Unfortunately, the first line gives me an error in the console of the Browser Firefox:

`TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: module`

The browser Chromium gives me the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Actually, giving relative references is not working either:

I installed the nodejs module "module" (`npm install module`) and used a relative path to that module. Unfortunately, the browser does not know how to load the module because no concrete entrypoint is given.

I just tried stick to the manual but had no luck:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename

What do you think? How should I change my code so that this works?

Many thanks in advance for your valuable advice.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you've installed the module using 'npm install module' command, try using commonJS pattern and include the module in the following way

```
const { createRequire } = require('module');
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried it, but my browser console gives me: Chromium:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'require' before initialization`: Firefox: `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'require' before initialization`. I'ts because require is not defined in my context. That's why I would like to create it with createRequire as a work around.

Comment: The suggestion about installing 'module' fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: the "module" npm package does not appear to be related to this at all.

Answer (score 2):

require() is used to load files in node, and module is a node module.

These things don't exist in browsers.

You do these things, and running mocha tests in node. There should be no browser, just a command line.